# Firmware coding - applicable standards

Tags: firmware, standard, code

I would like to know if there are any applicable standards when coding microcontroller firmware (ARM) in order to achieve a specific quality level.

In my case, I would like to code firmware for a consumer IoT BLE device.

Something similar to IPC standard when routing a PCB.

Comment: There are a few; MISRA (C, C++) is one and DO-178 (Aerospace, language agnostic) is another. There are also coding standards freely available that incorporate most of MISRA.

Comment: @PeterSmith Thank you for your commebt. For a consumer device, would there be a specific standard? I have added the target market where the microcontroller will be in.

Comment: @LazyTurtle consumer electronics are pretty much by definition "as cheap as possible, and needn't work reliably". So, the coding standard is "whatever our intern learned at university and still compiles", which everyone who's dealt with cheap consumer routers will confirm. Or camera firmware. Or toaster firmware. Or smart plug firmware. Or [connected sex toy firmware and server-side infrastructure](https://media.ccc.de/v/35c3-9523-internet_of_dongs)... Good code is really rather the exception, sadly.

Comment: (also, I think you might misinterpret what IPC standardizes. Also, seriously, have you looked at consumer electronics? Their routing tends to fulfill the safety requirements, usually, but that's about it.)

Comment: @PeterSmith Actually the DO-178 is not a coding standard but a development process definition. The DO do not set any rules about coding. I recommend following the MISRA for embedded development to avoid some undefined behaviour, and problems with fundamental types (int vs uint32_t)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your comments. I understand. Regarding the IPC standard, it s a good starting point when designg a PCB for multiple reasons (PCB manufacturing, assembly...). Obviously, there might be occasions where a designer has obviate a specific IPC standard, but I think IPC for PCB design is a good starting point.

Comment: @PeterSmith Thank you very much for all that information.

Comment: @LaboratorioGluon DO-178 is indeed a process but then all 'coding standards' are a process, to a great extent. I personally use Barr Group's standard.https://barrgroup.com/embedded-systems/books/embedded-c-coding-standard

Comment: @LazyTurtle you're really misinterpreting what IPC is.. it's not a single standard for routing, but a standard suite aimed at setting reliable "interfaces" between the parties in electronics production. As far as I know, nothing in the standard is said about "good routing".

Comment: (But I'd love to be proven wrong, here!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, and as part of the final product quality depends on the design and the effort applied on following good practices, I will always advocate for following a specific standard as it will, in most of the cases, lead into good practices when designing. The fact that there are designers not following any standard for a consumer electronics product is not a sufficient reason for me to not try to achieve the best quality possible in my design.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, IPC standard covers multiple layers in what PCB/PCBA ¡manufacturing, assembly design, etc refers to. As already mentioned, IPC related to PCB design covers footprint design, recommended clearances etc... But please, I just was asking for FW coding standards for consumer electronics, I mentioned the IPC as an example, and I think it is a good example as it clearly seems to be understood.

Comment: @MarcusMüller And yes, IPC also includes routing recommendations. Check for instance IPC7095 where lots of advice is given on how to proceed with BGA fanout techniques, solder lands for BGA components. Or IPC-2221A where the Conductor Optimization between lands where a specific routing is recommended, or the preferred location for test circuitry (what implies directly in the routing of your PCB). I repeat, these are good practices and, if it is possible to apply them in your design, it will lower or eliminate risk of not having a PCB compliant with manufacturability and / or realiability.

Comment: @LazyTurtle thanks! I really do love to learn that I was wrong here – this is a good resource!

Comment: @MarcusMüller You´re welcome :-). It´s great to be able to discuss about electronics in this forum, a good learning resource indeed,

Comment: Depending on what your IOT device is connected to, safety-critical standards may apply (for example for a garage door opener). Eg. IEC 60730.

Comment: Also note that in the case of "IoT" you also have quality standards for radio to consider, such as the applicable ETSI ones for Europe.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you very much for that information. But, are ETSI related to code itself?

Comment: @LazyTurtle Not unless the code is doing digital signal processing directly affecting the radio. They are radio standards concerning immunity & emissions and various other signal quality parameters. Mandatory for all radio equipment sold in Europe.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general code quality, there is [MISRA-C](https://www.misra.org.uk/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/160/Default.aspx) which is turning into the de facto standard for how to write C in embedded systems. It is focused on how to avoid bugs and reliance on poorly-defined behavior. MISRA has a strong focus on using static analysis tools in addition to the compiler, in order to weed out questionable code.

In addition, there are specific standards for how to write safety-related programs and manage quality control, in branch-specific ways. Most notably the "SIL standards" such as IEC 61508 for industrial, ISO 26262 for automotive and IEC 60730 for consumer/household electronics. Or the specific DO-178 standard for aerospace. All of these have their own rules for how to design safety-related software (some good, some bad). All of them require that you use a safe subset of the programming language, in practice limiting your options to either MISRA-C or SPARK Ada.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have really found after writing code for about 35 years.   There are some guidelines about what NOT to do, but it doesn't build in quality.  "Quality" in software is a very intangible thing and very hard to measure.

MISRA rules make some sense but are not always applicable to current coding practice.  I understand where they are coming from but you have to think about them intelligently and understand the context of what they were meant to accomplish or prevent.

IMO, good software quality is more a function of the thought process of the person who writes the code.  Things that lead to reliable code are:

1)  Understanding the problem you have.   Most code to solve a problem is written for the first time (after all, who would write it again if it works the first time?) and the problem is not always 100% completely understood when you start.  You learn the nuances as you go along.  Knowing those at the start tends to avoid strange approaches to solving problems.

2)  Having a structured mind and applying it to a problem.  Some people can do it, some can't.  You have to always think about the code as a communication to the next person who comes along and teaching them how to think about the problem you are solving with the code you use.  It's called empathy, and many coders don't have it.  Or don't take the time to use it.

3)  Knowing your language well.  Many coders take the opportunity to apply every possible technique to every project, even if it isn't helpful.  C++ Templates or exceptions are useful for certain things but you don't use them in every source file, just like you don't put every ingredient in your kitchen into the same cake.  Knowing how and when to apply your tools is important.

4)  Comments and layout are important.  Really.  For the most part, coders are lazy.  They try to pack as many characters into as small of a space as possible and press as few keys as possible to do that.  This is not helpful.  Good code tends to do things in discrete chunks (some loop to do something, or some initializations, etc).  I like to add blank lines and comments to define certain areas where a task is being performed.  It makes you structure your thoughts as to what you are doing and how to describe it, which tends to give good results for quality.

It is really hard to write quality software.  when you say "achieve a specific quality level" then you are assuming there are multiple discrete levels and they have been defined.   It doesn't work that way.   You can still use every guideline or standard in the book and end up with an unintelligible mess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand your point.